# MySQL/Java How to allow access to local host on mac

Tags: java, mysql, macos, terminal

I continue to receive this error when running by java program.

```
SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
SQLState: 28000
Error code: 1045
```

I have tried several different ways that I read on stack already. I have reset the password to nothing. Also when I am in the terminal some of the commands do not work. For instance when I type in `mysql -u root`, it comes back with command not found.

I've been able to access it by using `cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/`

Comment: My recommendation is that you set a root password for your local machine and use it at least until you understand the problem. The "command not found" error is because your /usr/local/mysql/bin folder is not in your user account path environment variable list. Look up how to set your PATH env variable and add the mysql bin directory. When you are in /usr/local/mysql/bin it works because your current directory is probably in your path. Hope that gets you a step closer.